# Guardar el contenido de un array en un .txt usando foreach PHP

Tags: php, array

Busco como guardar el contenido de un array en un `.txt:`

```
<?php
$resul = array('hermaniribeiro', 'Ebtsama', 'BrittoOFC', 'CheesterG', 'dsolutec', 'ExpoGanSon', 'dsolutec', 'ExpoGanSon', 'dsolutec', 'BelforFx', 'kunakrec', 'YouTube', 'Dasabuvir', 'greentechmedia', 'bardomsw', 'MdeMotion', 'iAnonymous', 'WilliamCorvera', 'MadridVen', 'Bertty17', 'SoyBobMarley', 'joseapontefelip', 'la_patilla', 'hootsuite', 'fawkestar70', 'starwars');

$file = fopen("user.txt", "a");
foreach($resul as $final){
fwrite($file, PHP_EOL ."$final");
}
 fclose($file);
?>
```

Lo intento de esa manera pero solo imprime el resultado pero no lo guarda y lo que busco es que lo guarde igual que lo imprime con salto de linea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buenas,

Un array es una clase de objeto dinámico, por lo que no le serviría para alojar contenido estático (sin intervención del lado del servidor). Sin embargo, puede utilizar un lenguaje de serializado como lo es JSON.

Utilice `json_encode()` para llevar a cabo el guardado, y para evitar confusión, sugiero que modifique el nombre del fichero a extension `.json`

Si no es el caso y simplemente quiere alojar un contenido a *la rápida* puede utilizar un bucle como`foreach`

```
$nombres = [];
$contenido = "";
foreach($nombres as $nombre){
  $contenido .= $nombre."\n";
}
file_put_contents(__DIR__."/nombres.json", $contenido);
```

Espero haberle servido de ayuda y que tenga una linda noche

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta aunque no miro la necesidad de que modifique el nombre del fichero a extensión .json

Comment: Es para evitar confusion ya que almacenas la información en un bloque de información arbitrario serializado en notación de objetos de javascript,¿me explico?

Answer (score 2):

La opción de apertura de solo escritura `'w'` de [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php) `fopen("user.txt", "w");` truncará el contenido anterior, por lo cuál al final de la iteración solo tendrá el ultimo valor del array en el archivo.

Dos cosas importantes , por cada iteración estaría abriendo el archivo *(fopen)* 
  y cerrando *(fclose)*  `user.txt` , lo cuál es incorrecto debería ser fuera del `bucle`, además el fin de línea iría después del valor *(para mayor consistencia si no su archivo iniciará con un salto de línea)*.

```
$resul = array('hermaniribeiro', 'Ebtsama', 'BrittoOFC', 'CheesterG', 'dsolutec', 'ExpoGanSon', 'dsolutec', 'ExpoGanSon', 'dsolutec', 'BelforFx', 'kunakrec', 'YouTube', 'Dasabuvir', 'greentechmedia', 'bardomsw', 'MdeMotion', 'iAnonymous', 'WilliamCorvera', 'MadridVen', 'Bertty17', 'SoyBobMarley', 'joseapontefelip', 'la_patilla', 'hootsuite', 'fawkestar70', 'starwars');

$file = fopen("user.txt", "w"); // Abrir
foreach($resul as $final) {
    fwrite($file, $final.PHP_EOL);
}
fclose($file); // Cerrar
```

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración ya logre a serlo funcionar solo "a" en ves de "w"

Comment: Sí también es una opción válida. lo que si sería necesario es la apertura y el cierre fuera del ciclo. Saludos.